# Common Lisp: standalone executable and shared C library

Tags: shared-libraries, common-lisp, executable, sbcl

Until now, I have managed to build my Common Lisp project into a standalone executable with sbcl like this:

```
(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die "myexecutable" :toplevel #'main :executable t)
```

Also, I have made it to call C functions, compiled into a shared library, from common lisp; something like this:

```
(cffi:define-foreign-library libtest
      (:unix (:default "./libtest"))
      (t (:default "./libtest")))

(cffi:use-foreign-library libtest)
```

or using an absolute path for the library. The produced executable needs the shared library, libtest.so. I have both myexecutable and libtest.so in the same directory. However, if I use an absolute I cannot distribute those two files. If I use "./libtest" it doesn't find the library when run from another directory.

What is the approach for this case?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why can't you redistribute it you use an absolute path?

Comment: Let's say I put in "/home/me/src/my-project" and I write in the lisp file. When I distribute the two files, somehow the lisp file should be updated with the knowledge of the new path. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Although I think libraries are generally put in one system wide location (eg. `/usr/lib` on linux), why can't you just use a relative path?

Comment: You are right. I could put the shared library in a system wide location. But I was thinking something like the answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like `sb-ext:*runtime-pathname*` should give you the pathname of the executable.

```
* (describe '*runtime-pathname*)

SB-EXT:*RUNTIME-PATHNAME*
  [symbol]

*RUNTIME-PATHNAME* names a special variable:
  Value: #P"/usr/local/bin/sbcl"
  Documentation:
    The absolute pathname of the running SBCL runtime.
```

You can then compute a pathname for a file in the same directory:

```
* (merge-pathnames "libtest" *runtime-pathname*)

#P"/usr/local/bin/libtest"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.